# Is there a way to manually tell OS X to allocate additional resources to processing for an app?

Tags: macos, memory, cpu

I know that in some cases, opening up multiple instances of an app will get the job done, but I'm looking for a way to essentially tell OSX:

"If I'm running a process that will take awhile, and there is still plenty of 'room' to go around (in terms of available CPU/RAM/etc...), go ahead and allocate more resources to that app/process so it can finish sooner, as opposed to having a lot of the available resources just sitting there in case I start doing something else and need 'space.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [renice command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man8/renice.8.html) in Terminal to modify the scheduling priority of a running process.

First, find the PID of the process using Activity Monitor, or the `ps` command in Terminal.  For example, if you want to renice Quicktime Player, enter the following command in Terminal:

```
ps -A | grep QuickTime
```

This will print something like this, where 7997 is the PID:

```
7997 ??         8:23.86 /Applications/QuickTime Player.app/Contents/MacOS/QuickTime Player
```

Then execute renice (it must be run as root):

```
sudo renice -20 7997
```

-20 is the most favorable scheduling priority.

Answer (score 4):

No. OSX, like pretty much any modern OS allocates all resources that a program wants, if they're available. Pretty much the only exception is Windows XP, which keeps memory free. But that particular bug was fixed in Vista.